# How to increase the value of each item/element in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.x, decoder

I am currently trying to make a Caesar decoder, so I am trying to find out how to take user input of the value of the shift, and using that input to shift each item in a list. But each time I try, it just keeps giving me an error.

For example:

`word` in the ASCII would be:

```
[119, 111, 114, 100]
```

If the given input of shift was `2`, I would want the list to be:

```
[121, 113, 116, 102]
```

Please help. This is my first time programming and this Caesar Decoder is driving me crazy :(

This is what I have so far

```
import string

def main():

    inString = raw_input("Please enter the word to be "
                        "translated: ")
    key = raw_input("What is the key value or the shift? ")

    toConv = [ord(i) for i in inString] # now want to shift it by key value
    #toConv = [x+key for x in toConv]   # this is not working, error gives 'cannot add int and str

    print "This is toConv", toConv
```

Also, it would be helpful if you guys don't use any fancy functions.  Instead, please use the existing code. I am a newbie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string object and [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) returns an integer.  Moreover, as the error message states, you cannot add strings and integers together with `+`:

```
>>> 'a' + 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
>>>
```

However, that is exactly what you are trying to do here:

```
toConv = [x+key for x in toConv]
```

In the above code, `x` will be an integer (because `toConv` is a list of integers) and `key` will be a string (because you used `raw_input` to get its value).

---

You can fix the problem by simply converting the input into an integer:

```
key = int(raw_input("What is the key value or the shift? "))
```

Afterwards, your list comprehension will work as it should.

---

Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> def main():
...     inString = raw_input("Please enter the word to be "
...                         "translated: ")
...     # Make the input an integer
...     key = int(raw_input("What is the key value or the shift? "))
...     toConv = [ord(i) for i in inString]
...     toConv = [x+key for x in toConv]
...     print "This is toConv", toConv
...
>>> main()
Please enter the word to be translated: word
What is the key value or the shift? 2
This is toConv [121, 113, 116, 102]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in a one liner:

```
shifted_word = "".join([chr(ord(letter)+shift_value) for letter in word])
```